# How to change dtype of CASTable with SAS SWAT module in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sas

I am using SWAT module to access SAS data i Python. One key column contains categories in dtype: "char".

I have another dataframe that I import as CASTable like this:

```
conn = swat.CAS(host, port, username, password)    
meta = conn.read_csv("file.csv")
```

the meta dataframe have a similar column but it is imported as dtype: "varchar".

When I try to merge the two dataframes I get an error as the two key columns are have different dtypes (char and varchar),  but I can not figure out how to change dtype in a CASTable?

I have tried to change dtype in "read" time by adding `dtype = {"ColumnName": "str"}`, or `dtype = {"ColumnName": "char"}`. This return `TypeError: data type 'char' not understood`

How can I change dtype of CASTable with the SWAT module in Python (both the columns contain the exact same strings)? or is there another way to merge the two datasets that does not require me to have matching dtype.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to try a different load process, such as upload_file, as documented [here](https://sassoftware.github.io/python-swat/loading-data.html#using-server-side-parsers).  That might get you a different type.

Otherwise, the first thing I would do is try dtype=`char(#)` or `varchar(#)` where # is the length.  I don't think `char` by itself is a type, you have to have the length or SAS doesn't know how many bytes to store it in.  See the [CAS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=casref&docsetTarget=p00irrg1pxzro6n1aadfcb1p3cag.htm&locale=en) for more information.